# I request any troubleshooting for the audio in Webex

Tags: sound, performance, microphone, webex

I have Ubuntu 10.04 in Toshiba NB255-SP1002M 32 bits mini-notebook. I have installed Webex and its plugging sun java 6k and another utilities, following the next indications:

http://goinggnu.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/webex-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/

Apparently, webex works very fine; if you test it from the webex main page:

http://www.webex.com/test-meeting.html

It says "Congratulations! your system is now set up properly ...". We must remember it is a simulated procedure.

When I used by first time my system, in a real environment (in a course CCNP video-conference in real time), the video is fine, and the audio is fine. However, when I open the microphone, the audio vanish (they do not ear me, and I don't ear them) and by consequence I need to restart the application, so no opportunity exist for me to talk, but, if I subsequently open and close the microphone, I already do not ear the conference, so I need restart the webex and by consequence I loss minutes very importants.

In all the applications(i.e. skype, msn, etc) no problems exist with the audio. Only I have this problem with webex, so probably it's is any mismatch with the software webex or java with the ubuntu 10.04, as far as I know. So apparently the webex in my system is fine, but in order of the problem, above, it means a low and poor performance.

I have made all the available updates (synaptic, repositories, etc), and I have cleaned the system with BleachBit, so no I do not have any manner to test the system; the only opportunity that I have is waiting the next conference session, but it is critical moment, you know.

My question is, what is the problem and/or what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

A first step to diagnose this would be to start the application from console, something like

```
java -jar WhateverTheNameOfTheApp.jar
```

try to use it and see what messages are printed when the error occurs.

This may be a bit tricky to do if the only opportunity for you to test the application is in the real meeting call.

Since it's a paid application, I would imagine contacting the support would be a good option too.